Проверка наличия сертификатов Минцифры в браузере
Столкнулся с насущной проблемой, необходимо проверить наличие сертификатов "Минцифры" в браузере клиента. Минимальный ресерч по интернету не дал никаких результатов. Возможно кто-то представляет как это работает и готов поделится решением, или направлением куда копать.
Спасибо
